# Update pandas df with new values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframes together but when I do it, it seems to replace the existing values with blanks, which isn't really ideal.

```
df1

col1      col2
'house1'  300
'house2'  450
'house3'  750

df2

col1      col2
'house4'  600
```

the code I'm using to concat is:

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df1], sort=False, ignore_index=True)
```

which yields:

```
col1      col2
'house4'  600
'house1'  
'house2'  
'house3'
```

Is concat the wrong choice? I want to update all the values, but as said, it's overwriting the existing data. I'm sorry if I'm doing a terrible job at explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try append:

```
df = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add a row, you'll probably want to use [pandas append function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

Try this:

```
df = df1.append(df2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. Will I still be able to groupby and sum if the values I am grouping by exist in more than one row? (i.e. 2 rows with 'house1')?

Comment: You'll just create a new dataframe with the rows added to it, so yes you still should be able to perform the same operations (sum, groupby etc) as usual on this new dataframe.